# JqPlot plot to image is incorrect (delayed)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will show you my jqplot line chart

[image]

And To Plot Image

[image]

How I see that the bottom label numbers are delyed as his label.

My JQuery PlotToImage function

```
if (!$.jqplot.use_excanvas) {
         $('div.jqplot-target').each(function () {
            var outerDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
            var header = $(document.createElement('div'));
            var div = $(document.createElement('div'));

            outerDiv.append(header);
            outerDiv.append(div);

            outerDiv.addClass('jqplot-image-container');
            header.addClass('jqplot-image-container-header');
            div.addClass('jqplot-image-container-content');

            header.html('Right Click to Save Image As...');

            var close = $(document.createElement('a'));
            close.addClass('jqplot-image-container-close');
            close.html('Close');
            close.attr('href', '#');
            close.click(function () {
               $(this).parents('div.jqplot-image-container').hide(500);
               return false;
            })
            header.append(close);

            $(this).after(outerDiv);
            outerDiv.hide();

            outerDiv = header = div = close = null;

            if (!$.jqplot._noToImageButton) {
               var btn = $(document.createElement('button'));
               btn.text('View Plot Image');
               btn.addClass('jqplot-image-button');
               btn.on('click', { chart: $(this) }, function (evt) {
                  var imgelem = evt.data.chart.jqplotToImageElem();
                  var div = $(this).nextAll('div.jqplot-image-container').first();
                  div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').empty();
                  div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').append(imgelem);
                  div.show(500);
                  div = null;
               });

               $(this).after(btn);
               btn.after('<br />');
               btn = null;
            }
         });
      }
```

And CSS:

```
div.jqplot-image-container {
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    clear: both;
}

div.jqplot-image-container-header {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

div.jqplot-image-container-content {
    padding: 15px;
}

a.jqplot-image-container-close {
    float: right;
}
```

What causes my delayed label numbers ?

Comment: i too have had issues with jqplot in the past, i've moved to flot and have been happy. If you're not able to solve this issue, give flot a try (also a jquery based plotting plugin). http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: I am too invlolved in using jqplot...I cannot change to another library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

try to apply the CSS to `chart1` div  (using `var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [arrays], options);`) :

```
<div style='align: left'>
   <div id="chart1"></div>
   ....
</div>
```

and

```
#chart1
{
   width: 800px;
   height: 500px;
   margin:0;
}
```